# Acesso a Webservice Assíncrono

Tags: web-service, async

Estou trabalhando em um projeto, onde executo um webservice assíncrono(padrão do projeto), porém estou com problema pois o webservice ainda não finalizou a execução e meu processamento continuo (ocasionando erros).

Existe alguma forma que eu possa fazer para só continuar o processamento após finalizar a execução do webservice?

Segue uma parte do código onde eu efetuo a chamada do webservice(gravar histórico) após uma alteração. Preciso que o processo continue (redirecionar), somente apos toda a execução do webservice (não posso alterar o webservice):

```
public ActionResult EditarConfirmed(EditarAnotacoesAdministrativasViewModel viewModel, long? handlePeg, long id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                viewModel.Entidade.Handle = id;
                repositorio.Altera(viewModel.Entidade);

                var proxy = new AnotacoesAdmPegServiceClient();
                var handleAnotacao = new anotacaoAdministrativaId() { codigo = viewModel.Entidade.Handle };

                proxy.gravarHistorico(2, handleAnotacao);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Id = viewModel.Entidade.Handle });
            }
            else
            {
                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sim, mas a resposta depende da framework que você estiver para chamar o webservice. Coloca o código do cliente do serviço aqui pra podermos elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: @Pizzanio, sem conhecer a estrutura do serviço, fica dificil de lhe ajudar, em todo caso o seu webservice parece não ser feito usando `WCF` ou está utilizando o modelo antigo para requisições assicronas (usando `DuplexChannel`, `CallbackContract` e Métodos `OneWay`). Neste caso, você terá de suspender a `thread` atual e esperar pelo retorno através do `Callback` para continuar... caso esteja utilizando o modelo simplificado para requisições assincronas do `WCF`, basta utilizar o `async`/`await` na sua `Controller`.

Comment: você poderia adicionar a seção `configuration/system.serviceModel` na sua pergunta, você pode e deve ocultar seções mais sensiveis, como a `security` dentro do `binding` e o `address` dentro do `client/endpoint`. porém o tipo do `binding` e a configuração do mesmo são importantes.

Comment: tentei usar async/await, porém não esta dando erro aparentemente de versão, pesquisei sobre o erro e ele pede para eu incluir uns packages, porém não tenho autorização para isso. É um projeto onde o cliente não autoriza eu sair muito do padrão do ambiente ja existente.